# Network connection timeout from docker container on high load

Tags: docker, networking, amazon-eks

We are struggling with the problem of getting request time-outs.
Basically, our service( HTTP node js based) is supposed to support a high request rate,
thousands per second. The service is deployed on AWS EKS and works. The problem we run into is multiple time-outs my clients start getting when the request rate exceeds a certain
rate.

To investigate the problem and eliminate infra layers, we minimize the number of components while the timeouts issue still happens.

At the moment we have two extremely simple setups where on one of them we clearly replicate the problem

1. Three HTTP clients load the service with 1K RPS each one whereas the service is
   deployed directly on EC2 machine.
   Monitoring this setup any time-out error wasn't observed.
2. The same three HTTP clients load the service with 1K RPS each in this case the service
   is deployed as a docker container. after 1K RPS, we start getting a time-out.

Observing the two settings, I found that the docker container contains 3 times as many TIME_WAIT connections.

- Docker container: 35K-45K
- EC2 instance: max 16K

have said that, I tried to reduce the TIME_WAIT playing with sysctl setting here is the docker container network config I was experimenting with

```
 docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 8084:8084 \
    --sysctl net.core.somaxconn=50000 \
    --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=30000 \
    --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=10 \
    --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1 \
    --sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait=5 \
....
```

Unfortunately, it didn't greatly improve the overall picture
The new sysctl values were actually applied. I verified it with `sysctl -a`.

I guess our problem somewhere inside docker container network-tuning.
Pls, point me to the relevant resource on how to start to cope it with.

Answer (score 0):

> The same three HTTP clients load the service with 1K RPS each in this case the service
> is deployed as a docker container.

Is that inside the EKS cluster, or a standalone docker host on a different EC2 instance?

If you haven't checked that scenario, please do so - it seems rather strange that just running the application in a container causes timeouts.

If all of your timeouts are observed only in EKS then you can check the IngressController in your cluster - might be a resource issue. Another option is to check the AWS loadbalancer, although it seems unlikely for 1k requests per second.

Comment: The clients run as pods in the EKS cluster whereas the docker host on a different EC2 instance with a separate docker engine, not related to the EKS. In both cases, clients communicate directly. So the only difference is where the service is deployed. EC2 vs the Docker container in the same EC2. The way I start the container is pretty straightforward

Comment: Could it be something related to how the application handles requests? Does it spawn different threads? I'd probably start with some basic 'docker stats' monitoring in real-time, while testing, so I can see the resource consumption - just to be sure that CPU and memory can be excluded. Try using 'docker inspect' on the application container, just to confirm that there are no limits imposed as well. And I guess your best chance will be to attach some sort of debugger/profiler to pinpoint the problem. Maybe also checking syscalls during execution can point you to something.

Comment: I updated the ticket with more debugger/profiler details. I thought the main direction I suspect the timeouts come from. The exhausted connection pool.

Comment: If the application is forwarding it's port outside the container on port localhost:5000 for example, the whole communication is most likely passing through the docker0 interface. I suspect that this is what you're actually seeing: higher number of TCP connections on the host. Probably you need a mechanism to close the connections as soon as the communication is done or reuse them. Maybe you can also try to experiment with a larger EC2 instance and higher limit to 'maxconns' to confirm that.

Comment: in my scenario, clients and server both send [Connection", "close"], which I assume should instruct both sides to close connect and release resource once the request is processed. I thought the sysctl setting I set should do the necessary optimizations like reuse and high max maxconns. However, as I mentioned, I don't see that my config has any effect

Answer (score 0):

on windows machine, we tried to change time_wait interval using powershell command to add entry to windows registry:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' -Name 'TcpTimedWaitDelay' -Value '10' -PropertyType 'DWord'
```

however it was not working.

Until we set this on host machine (and restarted) where we were starting docker container from. Then new time_wait interval started to work inside docker container.